# Estimate coefficients of a system of linear inequalities

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, linear-programming

I have a system of n linear inequalities. I'm looking for some algorithm or module in python which will find out the values of the unknown parameters satisfying the most number of inequalities.

For eg. The inequalities are as follows:

```
0.5*x1 + 0.8*x2 + 0.4*x3 + x4 + x5 + 0.2*x6 > 0.5
0.2*x1 + 0.5*x2 + x3 + 0.8*x4 + 0.4*x5 + 0.2*x6 > 0.5
0.7*x1 + 0.8*x2 + 0.9*x3 + x4 + x5 + 0.2*x6 < 0.5
0.12*x1 + 0.8*x2 + 0.4*x3 + 0.45*x4 + x5 + 0.2*x6 < 0.5
.
.
.
and
x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6 = 1
```

here I want to find out the values of x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 and x6 satisfying the most number of inequalities possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a language-agnostic solution; you can implement this with any of the mixed-integer linear programming libraries in python, e.g. CPLEX, SCIP, glpk, etc.

The idea is that your problem can be represented as a mixed-integer linear program by adding some auxiliary binary variables `y`, using the "big M" technique.

You have a set of `k` inequalities of the form:

```
E[i]: sum[j=0..n] a[i][j]*x[j] <= b[i]
```

For each one of those constraint, pick a constant `M[j]` that is "big enough", that is always greater than the left-hand side minus the right-hand side of the inequality. Let `y[i]` be a binary variable associated with the constraint, and consider the modified inequality:

```
EM[i]: sum[j=0..n] a[i][j]*x[j] <= b[i] + M[i]*(1-y[i])
```

You can see that (provided `M[i]` is big enough):

- if `y[i]=0`, then `EM[i]` is always verified;
- if `y[i]=1` and `EM[i]` is verified, then `E[i]` is also verified.

Therefore, all you have to do is to solve the mixed-integer problem:

```
Minimize: sum[i=0..k] y[i]
Subject to: EM[i] for all i=0..k
            sum[j=0..n] x[j] = 1
```

Where `x` is an array of continuous variables and `y` is an array of binary variables.

Once you solve this problem, the component `x` of the solution are the values you are looking for. In addition, you can get the number of satisfied inequalities by counting the number of component with value `1` in the optimal value of `y`.

Answer (score -1):

Use Numpy package to solve this. Their Example

```
Solve the system of equations 3 * x0 + x1 = 9 and x0 + 2 * x1 = 8:

>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[3,1], [1,2]])
>>> b = np.array([9,8])
>>> x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
>>> x
array([ 2.,  3.])
```

Comment: Navin, I'm not looking to solve the system of linear equations instead I have system of linear INEQUALITIES that I know won't be satisfied for any values of x1,x2,....,x6 simultaneously. So I'm interested in those values of xs for which most of the inequalities are satisfied.
For example if x1=0.1,x2=0.3,......satisfies 10 inequalities out of 15 and x1=0.2,x2=0.4,.......satisfies 12 inequalities out of 15 then my solution should be the 2nd set of x values.

Comment: Could you post what you have done so far and where are you stuck.than i will have a look at code